# Using a wordpress plugin inside a page template of a child theme

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I have a child theme of twentytwelve and inside it I placed it a copy of the page.php file, renamed it and removed all the code from it, except the calls to get_header() and get_footer(). Inside this page I want to use the Wordpress Referral Lite plugin. It says to use the shortcode [referral_link], but I don't know how exactly. Could you explain please? Should I just paste that within my HTML tags, should I enclose it with php tags?

Comment: the plugin works when I paste the shortcode through the visual editor of a new page, but how do I make this happen inside a page template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this: `<?php echo do_shortcode('[yourshortcode]'); ?>` in the template file.